# Filtering out array objects based on property value - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of leads in my component but need to filter out all of the leads where selected is equal to true and store them in a variable.

How would I do this with AngularJS?

This is what I currently have but it is coming back as undefined:

```
var list = $filter("filter")($scope.leads, {
            selected: true
});
```

Note that some objects have the property: "selected": true and some don't.

Please let me know what (if any) further info you require.

Thanks

Comment: What value does `$scope.leads` have?

Comment: Do you use `true` or `"true"` values? Boolean and strings are different

Comment: Boolean. Sorry, have amended the above. Thanks

Comment: @Andrew It has an array of lead objects that container a variety of properties including the selected: true / false property

Comment: Are you injecting `$filter` in to the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an example of how to filter by selected. Take a look.

```js
var leads=[
{"name":"one","selected":true},
{"name":"two","selected":false},
{"name":"three"},
{"name":"four","selected":true}
];

var list = leads.filter(function(lead) {
           return lead.selected
});

console.log(list);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I thought using the angular filter service was a requirement. This is using the `Array.filter` method.

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce problem.

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.run(function($filter) {
    var $scope_leads=[
    {"name":"one","selected":true},
    {"name":"two","selected":false},
    {"name":"three"},
    {"name":"four","selected":true}
    ];

    var list = $filter("filter")($scope_leads, {
                selected: true
    });
    console.log(list);
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
<body>
```

Comment: Not sure why it wasn't working either! But the below worked! thanks for taking the time to help though.